# Combining Plain and Inset Grouped Style Cells in a Single UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView in my Swift-based UIKit app with a plain style, single section, and one cell type with a variable number of rows. I want to add another cell with the inset grouped style, but it seems that I can't change the table view style programmatically. Currently, I've created a second UITableView on top of the original one, but this isn't an ideal solution.

How can I effectively use these two different cell styles in a single UITableView?

Here's a summary of my setup:

Existing UITableView with plain style and dynamic rows.
Need to add a cell with the inset grouped style.
Currently, I've placed a second UITableView on top of the original one, which isn't a clean solution.
I'd like to know how to implement these two cell styles within a single UITableView and achieve the desired layout and functionality.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

If necessary, I can provide relevant code snippets to illustrate my current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The style is a table-level constant.

> You must specify the style of a table view when you create it, and you can’t change that style later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614886-init#discussion

There are no apparent ways of changing the style by section, so if you want to do just one table, you will need to implement the look of `.insetGrouped` in your table layout.

But the styles are mutually exclusive, they are just layouts that Apple implemented, but the details remain opaque.

You have already stated that you do not like the "different table for each section" approach, so you will have to probably use `.plain`, and then decorate the cells to reverse engineer the look.

Comment: But you _can_ change the style by section if you use a collection view. And since a list-type collection view basically _is_ a table view, the OP could just abandon the use of UITableView altogether. Our app consists of nothing but single-column collection views; not a table view in sight.

Comment: @matt That seems worthy of a proper answer.

Comment: @HangarRash The OP has not provided enough information for me to know whether that information would be useful. I do not know what "add another cell with the inset grouped style" is intended to mean.